# Как оформить функцию "Непрочитанные сообщения"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как в диалогов выводить количество непрочитанных сообщений для каждого диалога?

таблица списка диалогов dialogs

```
user_id | recipient_id | ip
```

таблица сообщений dialog_messages

```
 dialog_id | replay | user_id | ip |
```

как мне при выводе списка диалогов выводить количество новых непрочитанных сообщений? и при выводе сообщений выделять непрочитанные например как в вк?

Comment: В показанном материале не видно ничего, что позволяет различить, прочитано сообщение или нет.

Comment: вот я и хочу узнать, как это лучше всего реализовать

Comment: Добавить в `dialog_messages` колонку `read` (0, 1) и считать сколько прочитанных/не прочитанных.

Comment: *Добавить в dialog_messages колонку read (0, 1)* ... и количество непрочитанных будет `COUNT(read) - SUM(read)`.

Comment: Вот есть готовое решение [месенжера](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger/blob/master/src/Models/Thread.php#L422-L425). Сделано через промежуточною таблицу, где хратися время последнего прочтения диалога